# MouseListener on Components used in ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, combobox, mouseevent, listcellrenderer

I have been trying to create to create a Custom Renderer for a `ComboBox` that allows me to have a clickable `JLabel` containing an `Icon` in every cell.

The Problem i am having is, that no `MouseEvent` seems to reach the components inside of the `JList` that is part of the `BasicComboPopup`.

This is the Component that returns the Component that should be rendered:

```
@Override
  public Component getListCellRendererComponent( final JList<? extends E> list, final @Nullable E value, final int index,
                                                 final boolean isSelected, final boolean cellHasFocus )
  {
    final Component plafComponent = plafRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent( list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus );

    if ( value instanceof String && value.equals( BasicComboBox.SEPARATOR ) )
    {
      return new JSeparator( SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL );
    }

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel( new MigLayout( new LC().fill().flowX().insetsAll( "0" ) ) );

    final Optional<JLabel> cast = Optionals.cast( plafComponent, JLabel.class );
    cast.ifPresent( label ->
    {
      label.setText( converter.apply( value ) );
      panel.add( label, new CC().growX().pushX() );
      panel.setBackground( label.getBackground() );
    } );

    if ( decideIfShowIcon.apply( value ) )
    {
      final IconLabelWithAction<E> iconLabel = new IconLabelWithAction<>( icon, onClickIconConsumer, value );
      panel.add( iconLabel, new CC().alignX( "center" ).gapRight( "5" ) );

      iconLabel.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
      {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased( final MouseEvent e )
        {
          System.out.println( "Never happens" );
        }
      } );
    }

    return panel;
  }
```

Drawing the icons works fine, they are just not clickable, I am uncertain why.

I have also tried catching the events on the `JList`, not even that worked.

Comment: Many Swing components, including a JList use a renderer, to display the data. A renderer is not a real component and doesn't receive events. Maybe you can use a single column JTable. You can display an "editor" when a cell is clicked.

Comment: I am well aware of that a renderer isn't a component, which is why i am creating the components myself and register listeners on them. I am not really looking for a workaround here, rather i want to know why it doesn't work and if someone confirms that it will never work like that or in a way that is close, i'll gladly accept a workaround, anyways, i don't see why the eventing should work better with a JTable, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: `i want to know why it doesn't work` - I just told you. A renderer is NOT a component. Your panel is never added to the JList so it can't receive events. When your panel is used as a renderer it simply means that the JLIst  will paint an image of your panel and its components onto the JList. `i don't see why the eventing should work better with a JTable` - a JTable allows you to edit the data of a cell. When you edit a cell a real component is added to the table to allow you to change the data in a cell. Read the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` for more information about editors.

Comment: Hm okay, i just used a workaround afterall. But thanks for explaining again, i got it ;D I calculated at what position the image should be, judging by its size and such and depending on if there should be anicon, i just ran my action.